# One of my posts was removed but I don't know why or what the post was

Tags: discussion

How do I find out what the post was and why it was removed?

Comment: You may want to accept the answer to prevent this old issue from being bumped by the Community user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No posts of yours were removed. I just checked. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: The OP did have a $-10$ reputation drop because of a removed user earlier today; perhaps that caused the confusion.

Comment: what is a removed user error?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: not _error_, Asaf wrote _earlier_. A user's account was [deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) earlier today. As a consequence all the reputation caused by his/her votes have been refunded.

Comment: oh that makes sense now